# When I use a name other than 'content.js' for the file, it doesn't get loaded. Why is that?

Tags: xcode, safari, safari-extension

I decided to load external JavaScript files because having 'content.js' as a single file was becoming too large. However, even when I added the file name to 'content_scripts/js', it wasn't getting loaded. Just to test, I changed the name from 'content.js' to 'content2.js', but it still didn't get loaded. In my environment, it seems that the file doesn't get loaded with any name other than 'content.js'. Do you know what could be causing this?
The files definitely exist, including 'content2.js'.

```
        {
            "js": [ //work fine
                "content.js"
            ],

　　　　　　　　 "js": [　// don't work
                "content2.js" 
            ],
　 　　　　　　　"js": [　// don't work
                "hogehoge.js" 
                // I want to add other js
            ],

            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ]
        }
    ],
```